# Creating a condition on a resource based on key-pair name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am attempting to limit ability to modify instances based on the use of key-pair name on an instance.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:RebootInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:ACCTNUMBER:key-pair": “keyPairName" 
                }
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:ACCTNUMBER:instance/*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

But for some reason this doesn't work. Can someone provide a simple example of how to do this? Or Better yet is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for providing key-pairs to aws policies is as follows:

```
arn:aws:ec2:region:account-id:key-pair/key-pair-name
```

Try changing your policy to use the following syntax, and maybe it will do the trick.
More info on arn syntax can be found in the following link - 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html

Also, try using the policy generator, and validating the policy, which also helps in these situations.
Good luck.

Comment: my understanding is that `condition-keys` need both a _key_ and a _value_. so using your example  

`arn:aws:ec2:region:account-id:key-pair/key-pair-name`

wont work with the condition block. @yaron-idan

Answer (score 0):

Update after more research. per Yodan Suggestion I took a look at the policy generator.

Short Answer: Not possible. Using the policy generator I obtained a list of possible *condition-keys* for ec2 resources.
[Condition Keys in Policy Generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsCo5.png)

It would be nice to be able to Have a key-pair condition though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it still appeared in my search.
Now we have the `EC2:KeyPairName` condition available. I think this is what the OP was looking for

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look directly possible to me.
When creating policies this is the [best documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html). In your case you want the [ec2 reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html) and there you can see the conditions you can apply (c.f. picture).
In your place I would either:

- Tag the ec2 instance and filter by tag (careful as this means `ec2:TagResource` may allow the user to tag an instance and get permission on it)
- Create the instance with a specific name or name prefix and filter by resource name instead of by condition

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:RebootInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances"
            ],
            "Resources":["arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:ACCTNUMBER:instance/fixed-instance-name",
                         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:ACCTNUMBER:instance/fixed-instance-prefix-*"]
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps, good luck !

[image: StartInstanceDocumentation]